# Custom layout in Toolbar with TabLayout below

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

Right now, I have a normal looking `Toolbar`. What I want to do is add a custom layout between the `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout`, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

On the left is what my `Toolbar` looks like now, and on the right is what I want it to look like.

As you can see, I want to add an `ImageView` and two `TextView`s to the layout.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want that section to collapse? Or just always the expanded height you've shown?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Preferably, when the user scrolls down, I'd like for the both the `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout` to disappear, and when the user scrolls up (but not all the way to the top), only show the `Toolbar` and not the `TabLayout`, and when the user scrolls all the way to the top, show both the entire `Toolbar` and `TabLayout`. If that's not something that's possible, then I'd prefer to have them both disappear on scroll and only show when the user scrolls all the way to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) extends `LinearLayout`, so you can add any number of views to your `AppBarLayout`: there's no reason to add the views specifically to your `Toolbar`.

You'll want to make sure you use the same `layout_scrollFlags` as your `Toolbar` if you want them to scroll the same.

Comment: This seems to work, but there are a few issues I've found. When I start scrolling in the `RecyclerView` area, the `RecyclerView` will begin scrolling before the `AppBarLayout` has fully been scrolled out of view (i.e. the `RecyclerView` scrolls in sync with the `AppBarLayout`). [Here's an image of what's happening](http://i.imgur.com/7lIlJu7.png). However, if I scroll on the `AppBarLayout` section of the screen, it scrolls as it should. Sometimes, if I fling lightly within the `RecyclerView` section of the screen, it can go through several items before the `AppBarLayout` scrolls out of view.

Comment: Secondly, is it possible to set scroll values that follow this pattern? when the user scrolls down, I'd like for the both the `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout` to disappear, and when the user scrolls up (but not all the way to the top), only show the `Toolbar` (not the profile layout bit, just the top-most part of the `Toolbar`) and not the `TabLayout`, and finally when the user scrolls all the way to the top, show both the entire `Toolbar` and `TabLayout`.

Comment: `AppBarLayout` controls all of the scrolling. I haven't seen the first scroll problem you saw, but flinging is certainly a known trickier problem. You might try adding `android:minHeight="0dp"` and use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"` to have your profile section be collapsed until you scroll to the top.

Comment: Is there any method that you would suggest to dealing with the flinging issue? Also, what view should I apply `android:minHeight="0dp"` and `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollap‌​sed"` on? I tried applying it to the `Toolbar`, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is just a ViewGroup, you can customize is as much as you want.

Try this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
 android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

This should bring your imageView in center of toolbar.